# Do CSS3 transitions delay event capture/bubbling?

Tags: events, css, transition

As you can see in [this example](http://jsbin.com/oxixoy/2), setting a `:hover` behavior for an element seems to delay its state from being recognized by its child elements.

For example this HTML,

```
<p>Here's some text.
<span>This will highlight later.</span>
Here's some more text.</p>
```

with CSS:

```
p:hover{
color:#FE6
}
p,span{
-webkit-transition-property:all;
-webkit-transition-duration:1s;
-moz-transition-property:all;
-moz-transition-duration:1s;
-o-transition-property:all;
-o-transition-duration:1s;
}
```

Makes the span begin its transition at the conclusion of the transition of the parent element. Is this by design, or, is this documented as a bug?

Comment: I don't see it this way (using FF 8.0). The span and the p all start and end their transitions at the same time. Edit: Actually, having tried this a few times in different ways, if I use the firebug inspector I see the difference, and the first time after doing so I see the difference but the rest of the time both elements do their transitions at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what happens is this:

> 1. Starting of transitions
>
> When the value of an animatable property changes, implementations must
>   decide what transitions to start based on the values of the
>   ‘transition-property’, ‘transition-duration’,
>   ‘transition-timing-function’, and ‘transition-delay’ properties at the
>   time of the change. Since this specification does not define what
>   property changes are considered simultaneous, authors should be aware
>   that changing any of the transition properties a small amount of time
>   after making a change that might transition can result in behavior
>   that varies between implementations, since the changes might be
>   considered simultaneous in some implementations but not others.
>
> Once the transition of a property has started, it must continue
>   running based on the original timing function, duration, and delay,
>   even if the ‘transition-timing-function’, ‘transition-duration’, or
>   ‘transition-delay’ property changes before the transition is complete.
>   **However, if the ‘transition-property’ property changes such that the
>   transition would not have started, the transition must stop (and the
>   property must immediately change to its final value).**
>
> Implementations must not start a transition when the computed value of
>   a property changes as a result of declarative animation (as opposed to
>   scripted animation).
>
> **Implementations also must not start a transition when the computed
>   value changes because it is inherited (directly or indirectly) from
>   another element that is transitioning the same property.**

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#the-transition-property-property-

Since you are specifying the selector as `p, span` and `span` is nested inside `p` the change of color in `p` stops the `span` and makes it delay.

Note that `color` is inherited so you don't need to specify it on both elements - `p` is enough.